# Different ways of sending image to an web api in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

What are the different ways of sending image to an web api,other than HttpWebRequest in **Windows Phone**.
Because i'm fed up with HttpWebRequest,and what i have tried in *HttpWebRequest* is [Linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927074/trouble-passing-image-to-server-in-wp7)

Comment: System.Net.Http.HttpClient is easier to use (available in a NuGet package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebClient is a much easier way of working with HTTP.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.95).aspx

It has an UploadStringAsync() method and an OpenWriteAsync() method to do uploading.